# Why cant I use power on functions?

Tags: matlab, exponent

I wrote this code:

```
t=linspace(0,pi)
x = @(t)sin(t)
```

then i tried this->

```
x = power(x,2)
```

but it gives me an error, how can i use the power function on a function then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

You can however use the power function *on the output of a function*.

```
x = @(t)sin(t); %this is an anonymous function

t=linspace(0,pi); % this is an array

x2 = power(x(t),2); % this is an array
```

Alternatively, you can create a second function that calls the first function

```
x2=@(t)power(x(t),2); % this is  an anonymous function
```

Comment: That said, I hope this is an example. Redefining the function `sin` to be named `x` makes no sense, just use the function `sin`.

Comment: `sin(t).^2` or `sin(linspace(0,pi)).^2` are other alternatives depending on the follow-on use --- see [`power`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html)